# Func<someType,someType=""> - What does the Equals sign mean?

Tags: c#, types, lambda, c#-4.0

Danny initially asked this question in response to a recent Scott Hanselman post:

> Who can tell me what's this :
>   Func<Customer, bool=""> A optional
>   parameter with default value? A empty
>   string for a bool? I replace it with
>   Func, and get the
>   different result in my machine!
>   Everything works well, I get "where"
>   statement without using Expression!

I know I've seen this Func madness, too, but I can't seem to get a Func<> or an Expression<Func<>> of this type to compile in C# 4.0.

Out of curiosity, what does the equals sign in the Func mean, if anything, and has that functionality been deprecated in C# 4.0?

[This question comes from Scott Hanselman’s blog: “[The Weekly Source Code 52 - You keep using that LINQ, I dunna think it means what you think it means.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode52YouKeepUsingThatLINQIDunnaThinkItMeansWhatYouThinkItMeans.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ScottHanselman+%28Scott+Hanselman+-+ComputerZen.com%29)”]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say you've seen it... I doubt that you've seen it in code which compiles.

If you have, please give an example: because until I see *real* code that way, I'm 99% sure it's just not valid C#.

Comment: Cool. That's all I needed to know. If Jon Skeet doesn't believe in it, then I don't believe in it. :)

Comment: @ewwwyn: The annoying thing is that just 12 hours ago I could have asked a C# language designer in person!

Comment: Mads Torgersen doesn't actually write code; the code assembles itself out of fear.

Comment: It as a bad format mistake in hanselmans highlighting software.  It has since been fixed, and was fixed before this post was made. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode52YouKeepUsingThatLINQIDunnaThinkItMeansWhatYouThinkItMeans.aspx

Answer (score 5):

According to the Visual C# 4.0 Language Specification, the ISO C# Language Specification (which is a subset of Visual C# 2.0), the Visual Studio 2010 Syntax Highlighter and the Visual C# 4.0 Compiler, this is not legal C# code. It isn't even *syntactically* legal, i.e. it doesn't even *parse*, let alone *semantically* legal.

Therefore, it simply doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to read [Scott's answer](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=887adfb1-0b00-4586-934f-50ccc2f15545#commentstart) in the comments, his blog software was playing up.

Nothing to see here!!

Answer (score 3):

- ^ What Matt says. Few things to watch for using SyntaxHighlighter in blog:

(1) http://bitbucket.org/alexg/syntaxhighlighter/issue/154/c-brush-lacks-c-3-and-4-keywords

Bug #154 C# brush lacks C#3 and 4 keywords 
  - group, orderby, from, var, select, ascending, descending, into, join, let, dynamic, add, remove, where (resulting in some LINQ syntax issues)

(2) hxxp://bitbucket.org/alexg/syntaxhighlighter/issue/165/using-in-code-produces

Bug #165 Using < and > in code produces < and ="">

Note: Be careful to use: `<script type="syntaxhighlighter" class="brush: csharp">`

(3) Yes Alex (SyntaxHighlighter) knows about it:

hxxp://alexgorbatchev.com/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=200&page=1#Item_0

Forum thread: LINQ not working in C#

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it's valid.
Even if `Func` supported optimal arguments, the last type argument is the *result*.